# Beginners Test the return of a metod

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

I've just began to work with Rhino-Mock, and I would like to test a basic method who check if pseudo and password is not null...

Here is my test method:

```
 public void ValidateLoginTest()
    {
        // Arrange
        var stubConnectionToTfs = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IConnectionToTfs>();
        stubConnectionToTfs.Expect(x => x.ValidateLogin()).Return(false);

        stubConnectionToTfs.Pseudo = "testPseudo";
        stubConnectionToTfs.Password = "testPasswordl";
        stubConnectionToTfs.Expect(x => x.ValidateLogin()).Return(true);

        // Act

        // Assert
        stubConnectionToTfs.VerifyAllExpectations();

}
```

Maybe I didn't understand howrhino-mock works but I tought that if I called my ValidateLogin method without setting my Pseudo and Password properties, and then call VerifyAllExpectations() it will be enough to test my method...

The thing is, if I comment my Setters, the test pass anyway...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to set expectancies you have to use a Mock, not a stub.